# dispatch data to firebase with react/redux

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to push the values in the input field to the firebase app. I have managed to fetch data from it but i can't seem to understand the submit function. I feel like i'm missing something really simple. When i try to use savePost it says it's not a function.

```
the action is:   
 export function savePost(post) {
  return dispatch => database.push(post)
}
```

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { savePost } from '../actions/index';

class AddPost extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
      title: '',
      body: ''
    }
    this.onChangeTitle = this.onChangeTitle.bind(this)
    this.onChangeBody = this.onChangeBody.bind(this)
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
  }
  
  onChangeTitle(e){
    this.setState({
      title: e.target.value,
    })
  }
  onChangeBody(e){
    this.setState({
      body: e.target.value,
    })
  }
  onSubmit(e, values) {
    e.preventDefault();
    savePost(this.state)
  }
 
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="container">
       <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
       <input value={this.state.title} onChange={this.onChangeTitle}  type="text" name="title" />
       <input value={this.state.body} onChange={this.onChangeBody} type="text" name="body"/>
       <button type="submit">Post</button>
       </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  savePost: dispatch(savePost())
});

export default connect(undefined, mapDispatchToProps)(AddPost);
```

Comment: Can you post what your `configureStore.js` or `store.js` looks like?

Comment: doesn't it need to be `this.props.savePost`

Comment: const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(Reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'))
registerServiceWorker()

Answer (score 1):

It kinda worked when i changed the mapDispatchToProps to:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = () => {
  return {
    savePost: savePost
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your `onSubmit(e, values)` function, you are calling `savePost(this.state)` which is actually calling the function you have imported at the top of the file.

The following code adds the function to the props of the component:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    savePost: dispatch(savePost())
});
```

So you need to do

```
onSubmit(e, values) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.props.dispatch(savePost(this.state))
}
```

Comment: when i do that i get "this.props.savePost is not a function"

Comment: @ssenn apologies, it would be `this.props.dispatch.savePost(this.state)`. Edited answer to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to
`const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    savePost: foo => dispatch(savePost(foo))
});`

and in the function, it should be `this.props.savePost(this.state.foo)`